# Two dimensional dictionary with list as a value python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm writing a simple parser for exercise and I have a problem with saving downloaded data to a dictionary.

```
data = {"":{"":[]}}

with open("Training_01.txt", "r") as open_file:
    text = open_file.read()
    text = text.split("\n")

    for i in text:
        i = i.split("/")
        try:
           data[i[1]] = {i[2]:[].append(i[3])}
        except:
            print("Can't")
```

This is an example of the data that I want to parse:

```
/a/abbey/sun_aobrvxdhumowzajn.jpg
/a/abbey/sun_apstfzmbeiwbjqvb.jpg
/a/abbey/sun_apyilcssuybumhbu.jpg
/a/abbey/sun_arrohcvipmrghrzh.jpg
/a/abbey/sun_asgeghboyugsatii.jpg
/a/airplane_cabin/sun_blczihbhbntqccux.jpg
/a/airplane_cabin/sun_ayzaayjpoknjvpds.jpg
/a/airplane_cabin/sun_afuoinkozbbhqksk.jpg
/b/butte/sun_asfnwmuzhtjrztns.jpg
/b/butte/sun_ajzkngginlffsozz.jpg
/b/butte/sun_adonkmfgywrhpakt.jpg
/c/cabin/outdoor/sun_atqvmarllxqynnks.jpg
/c/cabin/outdoor/sun_acfcobswmnoyhyfi.jpg
/c/cabin/outdoor/sun_afgjdqosvakljsmc.jpg
```

I want to create dictionary with "a","b","c" or any letter, as a key (I cant hard code it) with dictionary as a value that contains place where images were taken and list of images.

But when I want to read my saved data I'm getting `None` as a value

```
 print(data["a"])
 Output: {'auto_factory': None}
```

Comment: Where does 'auto_factory' come from?

Comment: I have 19 000 lines like this and `auto_factory` is the last one with index `/a/`. It's just an example. Link for a file with data: http://www.practicepython.org/assets/Training_01.txt

Comment: Is there a limit to how many nested levels the dictionary will have? For example, `{'c': {'cabin': {'outdoor': 'sun_atqvmarllxqynnks.jpg'}}}`

Comment: I think it will be max `{'c': {'cabin': {'outdoor': 'sun_atqvmarllxqynnks.jpg'}}}` but I'm not sure, there is no limit specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from python stdlib. It's very convenient in situations like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

with open("Training_01.txt", "r") as open_file:
    text = open_file.read()
    text = text.split("\n")

    for line in text:
        try:
            _, key, subkey, rem = line.split("/", 3)
            data[key][subkey].append(rem)        
        except:
            print("Can't")

print(data)
```

Explanation: the first time you access `data` (which is a dictionary) with a not existing key, a new entry for such a key will be created. This entry is going to be again a defaultdict, but the first try you access it with a not existing key, again a new (nested this time) entry will be created. And this entry will be a `list`. So, then you can safely append a new element to such a list.

**UPD:** Here is a way to implement the same requirement but without `defaultdict`:

```
data = {}  # just a plain dict
# for ...:
    data[key] = data.get(key, {})  # try to access the key, if it doesn't exist - create a new dict entry for such a key
    data[key][subkey] = data[key].get(subkey, [])  # same as above but for the sub key
    data[key][subkey].append(rem)  # finally do the job
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to do it in default python because I'm studying for an exam on which I can't use any modules.

Comment: It is a default python. But wait a minute, I will show how it can be done without `defaultdict` and you will see how beautiful the python's standard library is.

Comment: To sum up, I can't assign value to second layer dictionary before i check/create first layer? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, before accessing the second level one needs to check and maybe create an entry on the first level. `dict.get(key, default_value)` just simplifies this pattern to a single call.

Comment: Creating two layers in one line won't work as well? I mean something like `dict[lay1][lay2] = value` if layer one haven't been created yet.

Comment: That’s exactly what's `defaultdict` doing.

Answer (score 1):

Because `data[i[1]] = {i[2]:[].append(i[3])}` create a new 2nd layer dictionary everytime.

This is a possible solution. It is the cleanest solution, but it shows step by step. It creates a new dict and list if the key is not in the last layer dict. But it append value to the list if the dict has the key.

```
data = {"":{"":[]}}

with open("Training_01.txt", "r") as open_file:
    text = open_file.read()
    text = text.split("\n")

    for i in text:

        i = i.split("/")
        key_1 = i[1]
        key_2 = i[2]
        value = i[3]
        try:
            if key_1 in data.keys():  # Whether the key i[1] is in the 1st layer of the Dict
                if key_2 in data[key_1].keys():  # Whether the key i[2] is in the 2nd layer of the Dict
                    # Yes, Append to the list
                    data[key_1][key_2].append(value)
                else:
                    # No, Creat a new list
                    data[key_1][key_2] = [value]
            # if i[1] not in the 1st layer, creat a 2nd layer dict with i[2] as key, i[3] as value
            else:
                data[key_1] =  {key_2:[value]}
        except:


             print("Can't")
    print(data['a'])
```

Comment: While it's technically correct, for the sake of readability I would introduce meaningful names for `i[1]`, `i[2]`, etc. It'll be much easier to grasp the idea behind the snippet then.